# JAVA ANDROID AES CFB NOPADDING

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have created a Java file with following code that encrypt or decrypt a string:

```
public class Aes {
public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}

private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF }; 
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF }; 
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

public static String toHex(String txt) {
    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}

public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length() / 2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
                16).byteValue();
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
}
}
```

I have success tried encrypt a string, but not to decrypt it back... please help me. This is example code to encrypt that I tested before:

```
String data = "HELP";
String enc = "";
try {
enc = Aes.encrypt("1234567890", data);
Log.i("ENCRYPT", data + " TO " + enc);
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

AND RESULT IS : 48F1880B

My question is, how to decrypt it? I was test using my code above but result not equal to plaintext! please help me...

Comment: This is the second question that contains this defect `getRawKey(..)`implementation. Where do you all get this worse code from?

Comment: I get it from internet, and try to fix it, I just give an example, but I don't found a good example encrypt and decrypt with aes cfb mode, please help me :(

Comment: I get from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418336/java-simplecrypto-class-for-encryption-decryption-producing-different-results?rq=1

Comment: The answer from owlstead to that question already indicates that the code is bad - why did you take it anyway?

Comment: Can you help me? I can't found code example for aes cfb mode (128bit), so I try to test whatever I found :(

Comment: Sorry to say but it's not possible to write secure code by copy-pasting random code samples from the internet.

Comment: You are generating keys for decryption via a new seeded instance of `SecureRandom`. This can very well differ from your original key as seeding `SHA1PRNG` isn't very well defined. If your keys differ the decryption operation won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example class should give you a good reference of how to encrypt/decrypt properly with all the steps labeled:

```
public class AES {

    public static SecretKey generateAESKey(int bits) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
        //This method is provided as to securely generate a AES key of the given length.

        //In practice you can specify your own SecureRandom instance.
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(bits);
        return kgen.generateKey();
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(SecretKey key, byte[] plaintext) throws Exception{
        //In practice you should specify your SecureRandom implementation.
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

        //Generate random IV of 128-bit (AES block size)
        byte[] IV = new byte[128 / 8]; 
        rnd.nextBytes(IV);
        IvParameterSpec IVSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);

        //Create the cipher object to perform AES operations.
        //Specify Advanced Encryption Standard - Cipher Feedback Mode - No Padding
        Cipher AESCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");

        //Initialize the Cipher with the key and initialization vector.
        AESCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, IVSpec);

        //Encrypts the plaintext data
        byte[] ciphertext = AESCipher.doFinal(plaintext);

       /*
        * The IV must now be transferred with the ciphertext somehow. The easiest 
        * way to accomplish this would be to prepend the IV to the ciphertext 
        * message.
        */

        //Allocate new array to hold ciphertext + IV
        byte[] output = new byte[ciphertext.length + (128 / 8)];

        //Copy the respective parts into the array.
        System.arraycopy(IV, 0, output, 0, IV.length);
        System.arraycopy(ciphertext, 0, output, IV.length, ciphertext.length);

        return output;
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(SecretKey key, byte[] IV, byte[] ciphertext) throws Exception{
        //Create the cipher object to perform AES operations.
        //Specify Advanced Encryption Standard - Cipher Feedback Mode - No Padding
        Cipher AESCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");

        //Create the IvParameterSpec object from the raw IV
        IvParameterSpec IVSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);

        //Initialize the Cipher with the key and initialization vector.
        AESCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, IVSpec);

        //Decrypts the ciphertext data
        byte[] plaintext = AESCipher.doFinal(ciphertext);

        return plaintext;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //Demo the program

        String sPlaintext = "rainbows"; //String plaintext
        byte[] rPlaintext = sPlaintext.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")); //Raw byte array plaintext

        //We first need to generate a key of 128-bit
        SecretKey key = generateAESKey(128);

        //Encrypt the plaintext
        byte[] output = encrypt(key, rPlaintext);

        // ----------------- //

        //Extract the IV from the encryption output
        byte[] IV = new byte[128 / 8];
        byte[] ciphertext = new byte[output.length - (128 / 8)];

        System.arraycopy(output, 0, IV, 0, IV.length);
        System.arraycopy(output, IV.length, ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length);

        //Decrypt the ciphertext
        byte[] dPlaintext = decrypt(key, IV, ciphertext);

        String decryptedMessage = new String(dPlaintext, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        //Print stuff out
        System.out.println("Original message: " + sPlaintext);
        System.out.println("Original message bytes: " + Arrays.toString(rPlaintext));
        System.out.println("Encryption Output bytes: " + Arrays.toString(output));
        System.out.println("Decrypted message bytes: " + Arrays.toString(dPlaintext));
        System.out.println("Decrypted message: " + decryptedMessage);
    }
}
```

Few things to note however:

```
throws Exception
```

is not acceptable. This is only placed for the sake of simplifying code and should never be used in practice. Although some of those checked exceptions like `NoSuchAlgorithmException` is unlikely to be thrown please be wary that the `decrypt()` method **will thrown exceptions** for a failed decryption (i.e. bad key/IV/ciphertext).

Leading onto my next point, you **should not** rely on the `decrypt()` method throwing exceptions as a way to validate input. This should be one with a secure one-way hash function such as `SHA-2`.

Note how the key for encryption/decryption is generated **once**. AES is a symmetrical block cipher which means that the **same key is used for both encryption and decryption**. Please keep note of that and **not generate a new key between encryption and decryption** (you can however generate a new key per encryption if you want, as long as you use the same key to decrypt).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mainly in

```
public static String toHex(String txt) {
return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}

public static String fromHex(String hex) {
return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
int len = hexString.length() / 2;
byte[] result = new byte[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
            16).byteValue();
return result;
```

while converting `String` from `Hex String` you are not converting them with leading zeroes i.e. when ever you are converting a `char` and the possible value of that char is zero then hex value is also **00** ,by default your method simply ignores the one zero and adds only one zero to the Hex String

Note:- The numerical zero `0` is not equal to the Hex value of Zero.Hex value of zero is a null character, refer the ASCII table.

**with leading Zeroes**
`ef1b0030ef`
**without leading zeroes**
`ef1b030ef`