# Encrypt/Decrypt String Kotlin

Tags: encryption, kotlin, aes

I've created this two extensions in Kotlin to Encrypt/Decrypt strings:

```
fun String.encrypt(seed : String): String {
    val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
    val secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
    secureRandom.setSeed(seed.toByteArray())

    keyGenerator.init(128, secureRandom)
    val skey = keyGenerator.generateKey()
    val rawKey : ByteArray = skey.encoded

    val skeySpec = SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec)
    val byteArray = cipher.doFinal(this.toByteArray())

    return byteArray.toString()
}

fun String.decrypt(seed : String): String {
    val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
    val secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
    secureRandom.setSeed(seed.toByteArray())

    keyGenerator.init(128, secureRandom)
    val skey = keyGenerator.generateKey()
    val rawKey : ByteArray = skey.encoded

    val skeySpec = SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec)
    val byteArray = cipher.doFinal(this.toByteArray())

    return byteArray.toString()
}
```

for some reason I'm getting the following exception:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't define your cipher as just "AES".  Use "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding".  You'll also need to add an IV.

Comment: Besides that, using the `SecureRandom` class to *derive* keys is absolutely tosh. SHA1PRNG isn't well defined and may produce different values *including completely random values* even if the seed is identical. See all the info about `getRawKey` trap.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11420318/589259)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To encode your ciphertext use base 64 or hexadecimals. The Java API contains a Base64 class, so you're probably best off using that.

`byte[]#toString` doesn't do what you expect it to do; it simply returns a representation of the *byte array reference*, not the contents of the byte array.

---

Besides that:

- don't use SecureRandom to derive a key, try and lookup PBKDF2;
- explicitly use a mode of operation such as `"AES/GCM/NoPadding"`;
- use a unique IV, and a random IV if you decide to use CBC (usually insecure);
- don't use `toByteArray` without explicitly selecting a character encoding for the message.

Answer (score 20):

AES Encryption / Decryption using base64 key, salt and iv (Initialization Vector).

```
object AESEncyption {

const val secretKey = "tK5UTui+DPh8lIlBxya5XVsmeDCoUl6vHhdIESMB6sQ="
const val salt = "QWlGNHNhMTJTQWZ2bGhpV3U=" // base64 decode => AiF4sa12SAfvlhiWu
const val iv = "bVQzNFNhRkQ1Njc4UUFaWA==" // base64 decode => mT34SaFD5678QAZX

fun encrypt(strToEncrypt: String) :  String?
{
    try
    {
        val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(Base64.decode(iv, Base64.DEFAULT))

        val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")
        val spec =  PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), Base64.decode(salt, Base64.DEFAULT), 10000, 256)
        val tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec)
        val secretKey =  SecretKeySpec(tmp.encoded, "AES")

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec)
        return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)), Base64.DEFAULT)
    }
    catch (e: Exception)
    {
        println("Error while encrypting: $e")
    }
    return null
}

fun decrypt(strToDecrypt : String) : String? {
    try
    {

        val ivParameterSpec =  IvParameterSpec(Base64.decode(iv, Base64.DEFAULT))

        val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")
        val spec =  PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), Base64.decode(salt, Base64.DEFAULT), 10000, 256)
        val tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        val secretKey =  SecretKeySpec(tmp.encoded, "AES")

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);
        return  String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(strToDecrypt, Base64.DEFAULT)))
    }
    catch (e : Exception) {
        println("Error while decrypting: $e");
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

iOS [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60752764/8956604)

Comment: Thanks @Kasim, it works great...just one question the salt and keys you are using are safe?

Comment: @AkashBisariya , you can create your own salt and iv. You should only use 16 bytes strings. Look at the comment line.

Comment: but how these salt and iv are safe to use?

Comment: It is up to you how safe they will be. It is you who will develop the application. You will decide how you store them.

Comment: Is it secure to put "secretKey", "iv" , "salt" in the code?

Comment: Thanks Its working fine with this secretKey.. can i change it to other secretKey and how?

Comment: @SadeQdigitALLife this is a sample code

Comment: @SayedRizwanHashmi secretKey is a string, you can change it whatever you want

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir So where is the best place to store and use these critical keys?

Comment: @SadeQdigitALLife, 
it's all about the architecture of an application. Each user can have their own key. You can get the keys from the server. You can check this library. https://github.com/FredericJacobs/25519

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir, the salt could be in plain string too, right? No need to put it in base64 encoding, no? And then when creating PDEKeySpec, we could just pass salt.toByteArray for second parameter, no? Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Following Maarten Bodews guides I fix the issues as:

```
fun String.encrypt(password: String): String {
    val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(password.toByteArray(), "AES")
    val iv = ByteArray(16)
    val charArray = password.toCharArray()
    for (i in 0 until charArray.size){
        iv[i] = charArray[i].toByte()
    }
    val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv)

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec)

    val encryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(this.toByteArray())
    return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedValue, Base64.DEFAULT)
}

fun String.decrypt(password: String): String {
    val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(password.toByteArray(), "AES")
    val iv = ByteArray(16)
    val charArray = password.toCharArray()
    for (i in 0 until charArray.size){
        iv[i] = charArray[i].toByte()
    }
    val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv)

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec)

    val decryptedByteValue = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(this, Base64.DEFAULT))
    return String(decryptedByteValue)
}
```

Comment: You may want to lookup PBKDF2 as explained in my answer. Using the password as IV means you cannot encrypt more than one message with the same password. You may want to read into cryptography before continuing, or use a ready made solution. **Warning** above code is *not* secure.

Comment: The above comment can easily be solved by not using the password as IV. However, I get Unresolved reference: encodeToString and Unresolved reference: DEFAULT . What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way of implementing AES Encryption and Decryption in Android is to copy this class in your projects.

**Encrypt Strings**

Please copy the AESUtils class in your project first and then you can use it like this.

```
String encrypted = "";
String sourceStr = "This is any source string";
try {
    encrypted = AESUtils.encrypt(sourceStr);
    Log.d("TEST", "encrypted:" + encrypted);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Decrypt Strings**

```
String encrypted = "ANY_ENCRYPTED_STRING_HERE";
String decrypted = "";
try {
    decrypted = AESUtils.decrypt(encrypted);
    Log.d("TEST", "decrypted:" + decrypted);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**AESUtils Class**

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESUtils 
{

    private static final byte[] keyValue =
            new byte[]{'c', 'o', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'a', 'i', 'r', 's', 'c', 'o', 'm'};


    public static String encrypt(String cleartext)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey();
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encrypted)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

    private static byte[] getRawKey() throws Exception {
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
        byte[] raw = key.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKey skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypted)
            throws Exception {
        SecretKey skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length() / 2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
                    16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
            return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Encrypt and Decrypt in Kotlin like this

first you need:

```
val SECRET_KEY = "secretKey"
val SECRET_IV = "secretIV"
```

after that

Encrypt:

```
private fun String.encryptCBC(): String {
    val iv = IvParameterSpec(SECRET_IV.toByteArray())
    val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toByteArray(), "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv)
    val crypted = cipher.doFinal(this.toByteArray())
    val encodedByte = Base64.encode(crypted, Base64.DEFAULT)
    return String(encodedByte)
}
```

and Decrypt:

```
private fun String.decryptCBC(): String {
    val decodedByte: ByteArray = Base64.decode(this, Base64.DEFAULT)
    val iv = IvParameterSpec(SECRET_IV.toByteArray())
    val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toByteArray(), "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv)
    val output = cipher.doFinal(decodedByte)
    return String(output)
}
```

after that you can use it like this:

```
val strEncrypt = edt.text.toString().encryptCBC()
val strDecrypted = strEncrypt?.decryptCBC()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following  MarcForn guide I reduce it like this this:

```
const val encryptionKey = "ENCRYPTION_KEY"

fun String.cipherEncrypt(encryptionKey: String): String? {
    try {
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.toByteArray(), "AES")
        val iv = encryptionKey.toByteArray()
        val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv)

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec)

        val encryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(this.toByteArray())
        return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedValue, Base64.DEFAULT)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.message?.let{ Log.e("encryptor", it) }
    }
    return null
}

fun String.cipherDecrypt(encryptionKey: String): String? {
    try {
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.toByteArray(), "AES")
        val iv = encryptionKey.toByteArray()
        val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv)

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec)

        val decodedValue = Base64.decode(this, Base64.DEFAULT)
        val decryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(decodedValue)
        return String(decryptedValue)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.message?.let{ Log.e("decryptor", it) }
    }
    return null
}
```